# Passing data from client to server in a web-based application running on Android emulator is very slow

Tags: php, android, jquery, android-emulator, client-server

I developed a client-server mobile application using jQuery and PhP that performs mathematical tasks such as matrix multiplication. Both client and server codes are running on one mobile device/emulator using web server such as Paw. When running the app on real device, the task takes about 5ms to transmit data from client page to the server using POST and get the response. It takes about 20 ms to perform the computation in server page. So, the total time is about 25 ms.

However, when running the same code on emulator (the emulator is the same version of the real device, both are Android Nexus one), it takes 20-30 ms to perform computation (no wonder since emulator is slower), but transferring client data to server takes 20000 ms which is very strange. The data of request is something like "3000000" and the response is something like "yes", so there is no voluminous data transmission.

Thanks.

Comment: The emulator is generally slower than a regular device. I would not be surprised that it takes longer to do the same thing. I'd use the emulator only to make sure the code works, not to test real world performance.

Comment: Thanks Rarw, as I mentioned, it is true that simulators are slow, but 20000 ms difference in transmitting two words is too much difference, isn't it? I read Android networking guide and learn that every android emulator has a router and firewall, do you suspect that this delay is because of such processing task or so? If yes, is there any way to either ban the router/firewall or mitigate its delay?

Comment: I don't know why it is having that issue. But I can tell you that I have had the experience in the past where things that run smoothly on a real phone do not on the emulator. It is not always clear why.

Comment: thanks anyway. One upvote for your comments as a token of appreciation ;)